# In Modal View, DismissViewControllerAnimated After PresentViewController Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I come across this issue while doing some testing. I have presented a Modal view, called ModalView1. In ModalView1, when a button is pressed, another Modal view, called ModalView2 would be presented using `presentViewController`. Then I tried dismissing ModalView2 using `dismissViewControllerAnimated` but it is not working. 
Here is the code fragment in button action

```
- (void) buttonAction: (UIButton*) sender
{
    ModalView *ModalView2 = [[ModalView alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:ModalView2 animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think your modelview2 isn't dismiss right?

Comment: Why are you dismissing the second controller immediately after presenting it? Is it presented correctly?

Comment: @iAmbitious Yes, ModalView2 isn't dismiss

Comment: @JoshCaswell I am just doing some testing. The ModalView2 is presented correctly. I just cannot dismiss it immediately after presenting it.

Comment: I'm not understand why you want to open model 2 and dismiss immediately? It really Strange scenario.

Comment: BTW, dismiss your modelview2 in completion block of presentViewController method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. I give you two options:

Presenting ModalView2 and then dismissing ModalView2 (makes no sense to me, but that's what I can read in your question)

```
- (void) buttonAction: (UIButton*) sender {
    ModalView* modalView2 = [[ModalView alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:modalView2 animated:YES completion:^{
        [modalView2 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Presenting ModalView2 and dismissing ModalView1:

```
- (void) buttonAction: (UIButton*) sender {
    ModalView* modalView2 = [[ModalView alloc] init];
    UIViewController* presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [presentingViewController presentViewController:modalView2 animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Your first option is working. What I don't understand is why my way of calling [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; is not working.

Comment: Because you don't want to dismiss self, you want to dismiss modalView2. Don't you? And also, you can't execute two dismiss/present animations at the same time, so you have to wait for one to finish.

Answer (score 1):

at time present and dismiss not call so give some time

try this it working me

```
 - (void) buttonAction: (UIButton*) sender
    {


     [self performSelector:@selector(call) withObject:nil afterDelay:.4];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }


    -(void)call
    {
     ModalView *ModalView2 = [[ModalView alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:ModalView2 animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is giving me SIGABRT error. Anyway, you are trying to present ModalView2 after you dismiss the view controller. This is due to the delay. I want to present then only dismiss.

Comment: you can reduce delay time